# Trying to remember an English word that means “turmoil” or “tumult”

Tags: single-word-requests

The word is something like “fufura” or “furfuraw,” and I have even found a couple of web pages in which people use the latter in precisely the way I would use the word I’m trying to remember. But the thing I’m trying to recall would be on more than a couple of pages.

Comment: Might you be thinking of _kerfuffle_? Or perhaps even _furore_?

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer and remove it from the question

Comment: To match the forum's format, you can provide an example sentence in the question, and then provide your answer as a separate answer. You can even accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foofaraw

"**foofaraw:** a disturbance or to-do over a trifle"

Comment: I was introduced to this word by Kent Brockman on the Simpsons, during his report on the power plant strike - "Argle bargle, or foofaraw?"

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***brouhaha***:

> A noisy and overexcited reaction or response to something.
>   ‘*the **brouhaha** over those infamous commercials*’
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brouhaha)</sub>

While it is declining in popularity, it is used considerably more often than *foofaraw* ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brouhaha%2Cfoofaraw&year_start=1900&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrouhaha%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfoofaraw%3B%2Cc0)).

Comment: Brouhaha is a great word but not, in this case, the one I was trying to remember

Comment: I saw you had already self-answered, but this word has a similar meaning, cadence, and sound as your ask. So I thought it was worth putting up as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

***Furore*** is probably the word you are after.  Zut could be found in any thesaurus under ***turmoil***.

Comment: Per my edit above, the word is “foofaraw”

Comment: @MichaelStern Well, there we go!

Comment: It's a new one on me; I was surprised to find that it _is_ in dictionaries.